# "try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory" returns nil on only device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                  .setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback,
                               with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: UInt(UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP.rawValue))))
```

Returns the error:

> Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "(null)"

Comment: FYI - replace your `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: UInt(UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue) | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue) | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue) | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP.rawValue))` with `[.defaultToSpeaker,.allowAirPlay,.allowBluetooth,.allowBluetoothA2DP]`

Comment: replace it with what? @rmaddy

Comment: Please read my entire comment. It probably isn't related to your issue but it's the proper way to provide multiple options in Swift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone who finds this in the future here is the solve. It only works on device if you change `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` like this:

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                  .setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,
                               with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions(rawValue: UInt(UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue)
                                                                                | UInt8(AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP.rawValue))))
```

Comment: Yes, this is because the .allowAirPlay CategoryOption is only available for Category PlayAndRecord: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1771736-allowairplay

Comment: Swift 5:             try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                .setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord,
                         options: AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions(rawValue: UInt(UInt8(AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.defaultToSpeaker.rawValue)
                            | UInt8(AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowAirPlay.rawValue)
                            | UInt8(AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowBluetooth.rawValue)
                            | UInt8(AVAudioSession.CategoryOptions.allowBluetoothA2DP.rawValue))))